# i want to move all the data from my table to another table when button is clicked

Tags: php, yii

i have written the following code to insert a data to a table, and i want to add other buttons that if i click the button it will store all the data that i have inserted to this table into another table.

```
public function actionInsert()

{


     $nik = Yii::app()->session['nik'];
     $name= yii::app()->session['name'];
     $db = Yii::app()->db;


     $description = $_POST['description'] ;
     $amount= $_POST['amount'] ;
     $project = $_POST['project'];
     $status = "Not Approved";



       $query = "INSERT INTO pengajuan VALUES 
      ('NULL',NOW(),'$nik','$name','$description','$amount',
      'NULL','$project','$status','NULL')";
        $db->createCommand($query)->execute(); 

    $this->redirect(array(
            "pengajuan/index"
    ));
}
```

the problem is i dont know how can i solve this, i mean im confused, im thinking about using trigger but i dont really know how

Comment: You can do a select (from table) and then an insert (to table) with the selected values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2 SELECT * FROM TABLE1
```

Reference: https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3507171/Transferring-Data-from-One-Table-to-Another.htm